# How to convert a string to an object and then manipulate it in C#

Tags: string, winforms, textbox, coding-style, code-cleanup

To do what I intend to do, this code works for me, but I don't think it is the most appropriate or clean way to do it

```
public void func2(string S){
    for (int sum = 0; sum < 25; sum++){
        if (S == "textBox1"){
            textBox1.Left = sum * 5;
           }
        if (S == "textBox2"){
            textBox2.Left = sum * 5;
           }
        ...
    }
}
```

Instead of using such dirty code I want to use something like this (but well implemented)

```
public void func2(){
    for (int sum = 0; sum < 25; sum++){
        TextBox x = "textbox"+sum;
        x.Left = sum * 5;
    } 
}
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do by “moving” the given text box. In both snippets of code, it makes little sense to move them as the code does. The `for` loop is moving the same text box a little more with each iteration…? This is odd in a sense that the user would never see this, the user would only see the end product when `sum = 24`. The loop is unnecessary as `textbox.Left = 24 * 5;` will accomplish the same thing without the loop. Again, it is unclear what the code is trying to do.

Comment: In addition, the line `TextBox x = "textbox"+sum;` is obviously going to throw a conversion error as a `TextBox` and a `string` are two different types. If you want to use the `TextBox` objects, then I suggest adding them to a container like a `List<TextBox>`, then, you can loop through each `TextBox` object in the list and check the `TextBoxes` name property to figure out “which” text box it is.

Comment: do you want to iterate the textboxes and replace content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public async void func2()
        {
            
            List<TextBox> txtBList = Enumerable.Range(1, 25).Select(i => (TextBox)this.Controls["textbox" + i.ToString()]).ToList();
            txtBList.ForEach(leftDistance);
            await Task.Delay(100);
            txtList();

        }
        public void leftDistance(TextBox s)
        { 
            s.Left = sum * 5;
        }
```